# Custom function for merge pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, function

I have the below codes for merging :

```
df_merge_1 = pd.merge(df_order_products_prior, df_products, on="product_id", how="left")

df_merge_2 = pd.merge(df_order_products_prior, df_products, on=[“product_id”,”user_id] how=“inner”)
```

Is there a very generic function way that be written to use if for different merge ?

my function:

```
def merge_df(df1, df2):
    return pd.merge(
        df1, df2, how='inner', on=[“product_id”, ”user_id],
        suffixes=('', '_y')
```

But, I wanted it to more dynamic where I can pass the below values to the Function :

1. Column names by which it will merge ( it can be single column/ multiple columns - varies to case to case )
2. How - can vary (inner, left, right)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want something like this:

```
def merge_df(df1, df2, on, how='inner', suffixes=('', '_y')):
    return pd.merge(df1,
                    df2,
                    how=how,
                    on=on.split(','),
                    suffixes=suffixes)
```

Comment: No not really @zipa. The On argument users can specify either one column (or) as many columns. they may not give it in a list. just mention the column names

Comment: Sample function calls :
merge_df ( df1 = df1, df2 = df2, on = 'user_id','product_id', how = 'inner' )

merge_df ( df1 = df1, df2 = df2, on = 'product_id', how = ‘left’

Comment: @pyds_learner You can't use it like that as it will be parsed as positional argument and throw error, what you can do is pass the string in form `'user_id,product_id'` and split it on `,` like in edit. Single column will be parsed as list with single item.