# Insert Column in a Dataframe depending on another Dataframe with different shape

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with the same names in their columns but different sizes:

DF1 Shape(10x3)

```
Date         Client     ID 
---------------------------   
12-03-2020    Prada     AAA   
22-04-2020    Coutine   BBB
02-02-2020    MarioG    CCC
15-11-2020    Sublime   DDD
19-08-2020    Sublime   EEE
23-04-2020    Prada     FFF
30-07-2020    MarioG    GGG
11-10-2020    MarioG    HHH
07-03-2020    Prada     III
06-01-2020    Prada     JJJ
```

DF2 Shape(5x3)

```
Date          Client     ID 
---------------------------   
17-03-2020    MarioG    CCC   
25-05-2020    Sublime   EEE
04-02-2020    Prada     AAA 
15-10-2020    Sublime   DDD
30-08-2020    Coutine   BBB
```

What I need is to generate a column in DF1 called "Status", that says "Y" or "N" the ID of DF2 is present, for example, the result would be:

DF1

```
Date         Client     ID   Status
------------------------------------   
12-03-2020    Prada     AAA     Y
22-04-2020    Coutine   BBB     Y
02-02-2020    MarioG    CCC     Y
15-11-2020    Sublime   DDD     Y
19-08-2020    Sublime   EEE     Y
23-04-2020    Prada     FFF     N
30-07-2020    MarioG    GGG     N
11-10-2020    MarioG    HHH     N
07-03-2020    Prada     III     N
06-01-2020    Prada     JJJ     N
```

I have tried the following:

```
DF1["Status"] = ["Y" if DF1["ID"].values == DF2["ID"].values else "N" for x in  DF1["ID"]]
```

But it gives me error of lengths or dimensions of the dataframe.

Any recommendations to treat this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you [tried merging the dfs applying a custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56768300/custom-function-for-merge-pandas-dataframe)? You can drop undesired columns afterwards.

Comment: Merging or `Series.isin` would be most performant. Your attempt, however, is pretty close. Just change your comprehension to ask `['y' if s in df2['id'].values else 'n' for s in df1['id'].values]`

Comment: With ```series.isin``` the results ```DF1["Status"].value_counts()``` is N, 10 times... It´s not correct @ifly6

Comment: @ElthonDanielRivas So you did something wrong lol; `Series.isin` works properly (it also returns `True` or `False` and not `N`). Edit your question to include what specifically you ran.

Comment: Why are `22-04-2020    Coutine   BBB     N
02-02-2020    MarioG    CCC     N` marked as N when the IDs are present in both data frames?

Comment: @ifly6 I'm sorry, I already corrected the dataframe result... I confuse about ```series.isin``` so I applied this ``` DF1["Status"] = DF2["ID"].isin(DF1["ID"])``` and the result is just False  5... Should be, Y = 5 and N = 5.. Sorry, but i can´t understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the data with the following:

```
s1 = '''
Date         Client     ID 
12-03-2020    Prada     AAA   
22-04-2020    Coutine   BBB
02-02-2020    MarioG    CCC
15-11-2020    Sublime   DDD
19-08-2020    Sublime   EEE
23-04-2020    Prada     FFF
30-07-2020    MarioG    GGG
11-10-2020    MarioG    HHH
07-03-2020    Prada     III
06-01-2020    Prada     JJJ
'''
s2 = '''
Date          Client     ID  
17-03-2020    MarioG    CCC   
25-05-2020    Sublime   EEE
04-02-2020    Prada     AAA 
15-10-2020    Sublime   DDD
30-08-2020    Coutine   BBB
'''
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s1), sep=r'\s{2,}')
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s2), sep=r'\s{2,}')
```

Adding a column for `Status` creates the desired result:

```
>>> df1['Status'] = df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID']).replace({True: 'Y', False: 'N'})
>>> df1
         Date   Client   ID Status
0  12-03-2020    Prada  AAA      Y
1  22-04-2020  Coutine  BBB      Y
2  02-02-2020   MarioG  CCC      Y
3  15-11-2020  Sublime  DDD      Y
4  19-08-2020  Sublime  EEE      Y
5  23-04-2020    Prada  FFF      N
6  30-07-2020   MarioG  GGG      N
7  11-10-2020   MarioG  HHH      N
8  07-03-2020    Prada  III      N
9  06-01-2020    Prada  JJJ      N
```

Your initial solution with minor changes to the list comprehension (which I suggested in comments) also produces the correct result:

```
>>> np.array_equal(df1['Status'], 
...                ['Y' if s in df2['ID'].values else 'N' for s in df1['ID'].values])
True
```

Comment: thank you, your solution worked for me, with your solution also evaluate another way to solve ... Thanks again `df1["status"] = df1.apply(lambda x: "si" if df2["ID"].isin(x).any() else "no",axis=1)`